# Django Overwrite form data saved

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I've posted about this problem before, but I still haven't found a solution so I'm hoping I'll have better luck this time.

I have a form that takes inputted data by the user. In another page, I am creating the identical form that the user has populated (pre-filled with that information) for editing purposes. Users will come to this page to EDIT the information they have already put in. My problem is that it isn't overwriting the instance.

```
def edit(request):

   a = request.session.get('a',  None)

   if a is None:
       raise Http404('a was not found')

   if request.method == 'POST':
       form = Name_Form(request.POST, instance=a)
       if form.is_valid():
           j = form.save( commit=False )
           j.save()
   else:
       form = Name_Form( instance = a )
```

For this form, I'm using "unique_together" for some of the values. I'm also calling on `{{ form.non_field_errors }} in the template.

What is happening is when I make changes in the editing view, if the fields changes involves those defined in "unique_together" then an error is returned telling me that the instance already exists. Otherwise it saves a new instance. It isn't OVERWRITING.

Note that the reason i am using unique_together is that I want to prevent users from initially inputting the same form twice (before the editing stage, in the initial inputting view).

Any ideas?

EDIT: note that "a" refers to a session that includes a drop down box of all the available instances. This carried forward will indicate which instance the user wants to edit.
`

Comment: In the previous view, have you saved 'a' to the database before you add it to the session? What happens if you print a.id (I suspect it might be `None`)

Comment: yes they're saved to the database.. and when i do print it actually gives me the id.. not only that, but it is successfully prepopulating the form with all the fields of a, so it's definitely carrying it over.

Comment: "a" references a dropdown box in another view that the user will select that will indicate WHICH instance they want to edit

Comment: I'm still confused about what `a` is supposed to be. You keep saying it's a dropdown box, but you've used it as the `instance` parameter - so is it an instance of whatever model `NameForm` is editing? I think we need to see the code that creates `a`, as well as the model itself.

Comment: The instance argument *has* to be a model instance with a pk. Otherwise your form will always insert a new item in the database. If 'a' isn't the model instance you wish to edit, then you can't use it as the instance argument.

Comment: Did you check that "a" still holds the correct value when you receive the POST request?
BTW: I'd also suggest you use the url to get "a"

Comment: updating everyone: the problem was that I had this line in forms.py: 
if Name.objects.filter(name_id=name_id, name_last=name_last).count() > 0:
#                       raise forms.ValidationError("This Instance Already Exists")..... I don't know why this was causing a problem, but now everything works great. Thanks again every1 for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do a database lookup of the model your trying to save and pull the fields from the form to the model then save the model?

Answer (score 1):

Instead to store model `a` in session you should store it on database. Then edit it:

```
def edit(request, pk):

   a = A.objects.get( pk = pk)
   ...
```

**pk** it the `a` identifier, you can send it to view via urls.py. I encourage to you to use [POST/Redirect/GET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern.

You can add a 'state' field on your model to control workflow (*draft*, *valid*)

Comment: the model IS saved in the database.. "a" refers to a dropdown box in another view that the user will select that will indicate WHICH instance they want to edit..

Comment: I suggest to you to change method to translate instance to view. Use url instead session.

Answer (score 0):

You should not save objects in the session. If you really need to use a session - save a PK there and retrieve object right before giving it to Form. But the better solution is to send it in GET or POST parameters or included in url. Sessions are unreliable, data inside it can be destroyed between user's requests.

And you can retrieve value from a session in a more pythonic way:

```
try:
    a = request.session['a']
except KeyError:
    raise Http404('a was not found')
```